# view model in mvc4 showing errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a mvc4 application.Where users can create new projects and add comments on each project. ( I cant work out the comment adding part)

I have two models
1.Comment

```
public partial class Comment
    {
        public int CommentID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        public string Rating { get; set; }

        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    }
```

2.Project

```
public partial class Project
    {
        public Project()
        {
            this.Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
        }

        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Goal { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to display the following action links on project controllers index page :
Edit | Details | Delete | Add Comment
(The edit,details and delete functionalities are working fine but cant create comments)

This is my project controller :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ProjectCreation.Models;

namespace ProjectCreation.Controllers
{
    public class ProjectController : Controller
    {
        private ProjectCreationEntities db = new ProjectCreationEntities();

        //
        // GET: /Project/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Projects.ToList());


        }

        //
        // GET: /Project/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
            if (project == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(project);
        }


        //
        // GET: /Project/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Project/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Project project)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Projects.Add(project);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(project);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Project/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
            if (project == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(project);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Project/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Project project)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(project);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Project/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
            if (project == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(project);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Project/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
            db.Projects.Remove(project);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

      **  public ActionResult Comment(int id = 0)
        {
            Comment comment = db.Comments.Find(id);

            if (comment == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(comment);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Comment(Comment comment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Comments.Add(comment);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(comment);
        } **
    }
}
```

I somehow cant create a comment on clicking on the "Add Comment link ". Rest of the project controller is working fine. 
This is my comment controller action's view page :

```
@model ProjectCreation.Models.Comment

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Comment";
}

<h2>Comment</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Comment</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectID)

        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rating)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rating)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rating)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Can someone please guide me .I m passing the project id accurately.I cant seem to create a new comment.The view page is opened but nothing is updated. It even shows a drop down for project id instead of label.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

Your controller send the anoter Type of model then the view 'want'. The types  must be same

change

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectCreation.ViewModels.ProjectCreation>
```

to

```
@model List<ProjectCreation.ViewModels.ProjectCreation>
```

Comment: That leads to a compilation error 

'System.Collections.Generic.List<ProjectCreation.ViewModels.ProjectCreation>' does not contain a definition for 'Project' and no extension method 'Project' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ProjectCreation.ViewModels.ProjectCreation>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Comment(Comment comment)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Comments.Add(comment);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(comment);
}
```

You forgot to load the database and add a Create function(). It should be like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Comment(Comment comment)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var db = new ProjectCreationEntities())
        {
            var user = db.Comments.Create();
            user.CommentId = comment.CommentID;
            user.Title = comment.Title;
            user.ProjectId = comment.ProjectId;
            user.Rating = comment.Rating;
            db.Comments.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(comment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your view expacts model of type `ProjectCreation` 
and in your `ActionResult` your are passing `Project` model.

you must return `List<ProjectCreation>` in your ActionResult

### UPDATE:

`@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectID)` in your viewModel use [DisplayName("PropertyName")] attribute if you want your labelfor helper to show name you want

```
public class Comment
{
[DisplayName("PropertyName")]
public int ProjectId{get;set;}
}
```

for your comments to create you need ActionResult with HttpGet request

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Comment()
{
     var model = new Comment();
     return View(model);
}
```

and only then you will be able to post it
your ActionResult for Post:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Comment(Comment comment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Comments.Add(comment);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(comment);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've misunderstood your code a little but it seems to me you only have code to edit and save comments, not to create new ones.

This code snippet is from your own code. In the first function you only allow comments to be shown if they already exist. But how are you going to show the form for an uncreated one? It seems to me that when you try to create a new comment (and doesn't have an id yet) you'll end up with the HttpNotFound() reply.

```
    public ActionResult Comment(int id = 0)
    {
        Comment comment = db.Comments.Find(id);

        if (comment == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(comment);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Comment(Comment comment)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(comment);
    }
```

I would try to add a new action for creating new comments, maybe something like this:

```
    public ActionResult CreateComment()
    {
        return View("Comment");
    }
```